# Reorder a square array using a sorted 1D array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Let's say I have a symmetric n-by-n array `A` and a 1D array `x` of length n, where the rows/columns of `A` correspond to the entries of `x`, and `x` is ordered. Now assume both `A` and `x` are randomly rearranged, so that the rows/columns still correspond but they're no longer in order. How can I manipulate `A` to recover the correct order?

As an example: `x = array([1, 3, 2, 0])` and

```
A = array([[1, 3, 2, 0],
           [3, 9, 6, 0],
           [2, 6, 4, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

so the mapping from `x` to `A` in this example is `A[i][j] = x[i]*x[j]`. `x` should be sorted like `array([0, 1, 2, 3])` and I want to arrive at

```
A = array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 1, 2, 3],
           [0, 2, 4, 6],
           [0, 3, 6, 9]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple implementation would be

```
idx = np.argsort(x)
A = A[idx, :]
A = A[:, idx]
```

Another possibility would be (all credit to @mathfux):

```
A[np.ix_(idx, idx)]
```

Comment: @Mr.T You might like to use `a[np.ix_(idx, idx)]` instead of forcing these fancy indexes to work

Comment: @mathfux Yeah, me and numpy, we have a special relationship. Great suggestion. I was wondering how one constructs an index cross product. Thank you for bringing this to my attention.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that OP is looking for a flexible way to use indices that sorts both rows and columns of his mapping at once. What is more, OP might be interested in doing it in reverse, i.e. find and initial view of mapping if it's lost.

```
def mapping(x, my_map, return_index=True, return_inverse=True):
    idx = np.argsort(x)
    out = my_map(x[idx], x[idx])
    inv = np.empty_like(idx)
    inv[idx] = np.arange(len(idx))
    return out, idx, inv

x = np.array([1, 3, 2, 0])
a, idx, inv = mapping(x, np.multiply.outer) #sorted mapping
b = np.multiply.outer(x, x) #straight mapping

print(b)
>>> [[1 3 2 0]
     [3 9 6 0]
     [2 6 4 0]
     [0 0 0 0]]
print(a)
>>> [[0 0 0 0]
     [0 1 2 3]
     [0 2 4 6]
     [0 3 6 9]]

np.array_equal(b, a[np.ix_(inv, inv)]) #sorted to straight
>>> True
np.array_equal(a, b[np.ix_(idx, idx)]) #straight to sorted
>>> True
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `argsort` and fancy indexing:

```
idx = np.argsort(x)
A2 = A[idx[None], idx[:,None]]
```

output:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 2, 4, 6],
       [0, 3, 6, 9]])
```

Comment: Not quite. Perhaps I picked a poor example, because in this case your way works but it's not what I'm after. I want to sort both axes, but the way I want to sort them is with reference to the order of `x`, not `A`

Comment: OK, then you need to use `argsort`. I see @Mr.T provided you with the answer ;)